# C++ std::vector<std::pair<const int, int>> can not insert element

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main() {
  using kv = std::pair<const int ,int>;

  std::vector<kv> vec;
  kv a{1,1};
  vec.insert(vec.begin(),a);
}
```

I tried to insert element into that vector, but the compiler gives this eerror:

```
cannot assign to non-static data member 'first' with const-qualified type 'const int'
```

while `push_back()` will compile correctly.Why is that? And what's the correct way to insert element into such vector?

**ADD:**
The reason why I use `std::pair<const int, int>` is that I want to implement something like `std::map`, and the key in the key-value pair should not be modified. But I'm not sure if `std::pair<const int, int>` is the correct approach to do this.

Comment: Vector elements need to be copy assignable.

Comment: Use boost::flat_map<int,int> it already does what you likely want to implement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start by observing the following:

```
std::pair<const int, int> a, b;

a=b;
```

This will not compile either. Why?  Because you are in effect declaring the following class:

```
class my_pair {

public:
    // ... Bunch of irrelevant stuff

    const int first;
    int second;
};
```

This class has its default assignment operator deleted. The default assignment operator is equivalent to assigning class members individually:

```
pair<first,second> &operator=(const pair<first, second> &other)
{
   first=other.first;
   second=other.second;
   return *this;
}
```

This is a rough example of what a default assignment operator looks like.

But you can't modify the `first` class member, here, because it is a `const` class member. Hence, the default assignment operator is deleted. End result: cannot assign a `std::pair` with a `const` value to another such pair.

You should now be able to figure out by yourself why `insert()` on your vector of pairs doesn't work.

`insert`() is, roughly, equivalent to shifting over all existing values by one, in the vector, after the insertion point, to make room for the new value. In other words:

```
 value[n+1]=values[n];
```

For all values past the insertion point (I'm ignoring for the moment the work done to grow the vector by one value, which is irrelevant to this discussion).

But the default assignment operator, as I explained, is deleted because the `value` has a `const` class member.

`push_back` works because nothing needs to be inserted, only a new value needs to be added to the end of the vector. If the vector needs to be reallocated, to accomodate its growth, that uses copy or move constructors, which are still valid for a `std::pair` with a `const` value.

Comment: Nice explanation! And if I do want a container that contain some const pair, how should I do ? I think one way to do this is using a temp vector, poping out element to that temp vector, and push_back the element I want to insert, then push them back.  But this solution looks stupid, any alternative?

Comment: You can use a list or, perhaps, a set.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the `const` nature of the your data type `kv` (it has a `const` member `first`), it's copy-assignment operator has been implicitly deleted by the compiler.

Specifically, the overload of `std::vector::insert` you're using requires the data type  (`kv`) be *CopyAssignable* (can be copied with a form of `a = b`). Your const member prohibits that.

On the other hand, `std::vector::push_back` requires the type be *CopyInsertable* (it can be copy-constructed), which your type *is* compliant with.

Therefore, `insert` will not work, but `push_back` will. The easiest fix is to lose the `const` from the `kv` first member. If you don't want someone to modify a key/value, then don't let them. When returning key/value tuples do so as const pointers or references.

Comment: Sound like a reasonable solution for this. But sometime it's natural that we want to modify the `value` after we get that kv pair reference, any potential solution to this?